# How can I insert a value in a specified column together with the other columns without appearing it into a new another row alone?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a login logout system for our College Library that records the students' time in and time out whenever they enter or exit in our library.

I am using VS 2010 Ultimate for the form and SQL server 2008 r2 for my database.

In my database

i have 3 tables

tblCollegeinfo Contains : 
studentNumber(primary key), 
studentName, and 
studentCourse,

tblCollegeStudentLog contains their record with 
studentNumber again as the foreign key, 
studentTimeIn, 
studentTimeOut, 
studentDate and 
LoginNo and

tblCollegeStudentPassword contains
their Passwords with studentNumber again 
and studentPassword.

Actually my Log In button works, that whenever they entered their Username and Password and hit the Log In button they are now Logged In and their Student Number, Name, Course Login time (Time In) and Date appears in the ListView.

My problem is the Log out button. I don't know what correct code should i use. What correct SQL query should I use.

I have a hint that I should join the tables first and Insert the Log Out Time as the 'value' in the studentTimeOut of the table "tblCollegeStudentLog"

but I don't know how. Whenever I click the Log Out button with the SelectedItems in my ListView, instead the Logout Time(Time Out) inserted in the selected item it appears in another row. In short, how can I insert a value in a specified column together with the other columns without appearing into a new another row?
Please help me guys to solve this problem :( I hope you understand what I am trying to say :( I want that the inserted Value appears together with the other columns, because what only happens to me is that whenever i hit the Log Out button the value appears in another row alone it is not joining in the other columns :( thanks Guys!!! 
Heres the code:

Private Sub btnLogoutNow_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogoutNow.Click
        Connect()

```
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT tblCollegeStudentlog.LoginNo, tblCollegeStudentLog.studentNumber, tblCollegeInfo.studentName, tblCollegeInfo.studentCourse, tblCollegeStudentLog.studentTimeIn, tblCollegeStudentLog.studentTimeOut, tblCollegeStudentLog.studentDateIn FROM tblCollegeStudentLog LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCollegeInfo ON tblCollegeStudentLog.studentNumber = tblCollegeInfo.studentNumber WHERE  tblCollegeStudentLog.studentNumber = '" + lvwLog.SelectedItems(0).Text + "'", con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


    If dr.HasRows Then
        cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblCollegeStudentLog (studentTimeOut) VALUES     ('" + lblTimeOut.Text + "') WHERE studentNumber = '" + lvwLog.SelectedItems(0).Text + "' ", con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("You are now logged out!")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing. What would you like us to do with this?

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question so that it mentions the problem you're trying to solve. It really doesn't matter to us "Guys" that this is the code for your Logout button, and that information will also be meaningless to future readers who find it in a search result. While you're editing, you can also explain what the problem is with the code you've posted and actually ask a question. Thanks.

Comment: Don't repost. Edit your existing question if there is something wrong with it and don't create new questions for the same issue.

Comment: Done. Please Help thanks this is my assignment :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`. Assuming they are not able to log out unless they have logged in (i.e. there is record in `tblCollegeStudentLog` where `StudentTimeIn` is `NULL`, you can just use:

```
UPDATE  tblCollegeStudentLog
SET     StudentTimeOut = @OutTime
WHERE   StudentNumber = @StudentNumber
AND     StudentTimeOut IS NULL;
```

Then you would use [SqlParameters to properly execute the command](http://bobby-tables.com/) and not leave yourself vunerable to SqlInjection, poor SQL Plan caching and data type issues:

```
Dim Sql as String = "UPDATE tblCollegeStudentLog SET StudentTimeOut = @OutTime WHERE StudentNumber = @StudentNumber AND StudentTimeOut IS NULL;"
Using cmd = New SqlCommand(Sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OutTime", Convert.ToDateTime(lblTimeOutNya.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentNumber", lvwLog.SelectedItems(0).Text)
    con.Open()
    If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 0 Then
        'If no rows are affected then there was not a valid
        'record to update, i.e. the student was not logged in
        MsgBox("You were not logged in")
    Else
        MsgBox("You are now logged out!")
    End If
End Using
```

*N.B. Please excuse my VB.NET, I have not used it in quite some time so there may be some syntax errors.*

Comment: sir pardon me, but if i use update, it will also update the previous record (ex.yesterday) of his/her log out time.

Comment: No, because of the predicate `StudentTimeOut IS NULL` you are limiting it to only the record with no log out time, yesterdays record (assuming they correctly logged out) will have a value for `StudentTimeOut`, and not get updated.